# Sublime Text 3 - Package Control : "No packages available for installation" error when trying to install packages through secure channel

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04, package-control

I am running Sublime on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. I have tried installing Package Installer on Sublime Text 3 using both the simple script and manual installation methods.

Whenever I try to run the Install Package option I get an error message "There are no packages available for installation"

The console shows the following trace:

```
Package Control: Error downloading channel. b'curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:\n  CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt\n  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs' downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
error: Package Control
There are no packages available for installation
```

If I add `http://sublime.wbond.net/repositories.json` as a channel, install package starts showing the package list. But, when I try to install a package (e.g. Pretty JSON) I again get an error related to the security certificate with the following console trace:

```
reloading Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
Package Control: Error downloading package. b'curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:\n  CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt\n  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs' downloading https://codeload.github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson/zip/master.
error: Package Control

Unable to download Pretty JSON. Please view the console for more details.
theme loaded
ignored packages updated to: [Vintage]
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
theme loaded
reloading Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
theme loaded
```

Any suggestions to get Package Control to work with the secure channel are welcome.

**ADDITIONAL DEBUG TRACE FOR PACKAGE CONTROL:**

Upon enabling `debug` for *Package Control* I get the following trace:

```
Package Control: Fetching list of available packages
  Platform: linux-x64
  Sublime Text Version: 3059
  Package Control Version: 2.0.0
Package Control: Download Debug
  URL: https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json
  Resolved IP: 50.116.34.243
  Timeout: 30
Package Control: Found system CA bundle at /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
Package Control: Curl Debug Proxy
  http_proxy: 
  https_proxy: 
  proxy_username: 
  proxy_password: 
Package Control: Trying to execute command /usr/bin/curl --user-agent 'Sublime Package Control     v2.0.0' --connect-timeout 30 -sSL --compressed --dump-header /tmp/tmp_i20fq --cacert     /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -v https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json
Package Control: Curl HTTP Debug General
  Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    Trying 50.116.34.243...
  Connected to sublime.wbond.net (50.116.34.243) port 443 (#0)
  error setting certificate verify locations:
    CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  Closing connection 0
    CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
Package Control: Error downloading channel. curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations: downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
ignored packages updated to: [Vintage, Pretty JSON]
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
Package Control: Fetching list of available packages
  Platform: linux-x64
  Sublime Text Version: 3059
  Package Control Version: 2.0.0
theme loaded
Package Control: Download Debug
  URL: https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json
  Resolved IP: 50.116.34.243
  Timeout: 30
Package Control: Found system CA bundle at /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
Package Control: Curl Debug Proxy
  http_proxy: 
  https_proxy: 
  proxy_username: 
  proxy_password: 
Package Control: Trying to execute command /usr/bin/curl --user-agent 'Sublime Package Control     v2.0.0' --connect-timeout 30 -sSL --compressed --dump-header /tmp/tmpcg0ent --cacert     /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -v https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json
Package Control: Curl HTTP Debug General
  Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    Trying 50.116.34.243...
  Connected to sublime.wbond.net (50.116.34.243) port 443 (#0)
  error setting certificate verify locations:
    CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  Closing connection 0
    CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
Package Control: Error downloading channel. curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:    downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
Package Control: Unable to find a sublime-package file for Pretty JSON
Package Control: Unable to find file package-metadata.json in the package Pretty JSON
Package Control: Download Debug
  URL: https://codeload.github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson/zip/master
  Resolved IP: 192.30.252.146
  Timeout: 30
Package Control: Found system CA bundle at /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
Package Control: Curl Debug Proxy
  http_proxy: 
  https_proxy: 
  proxy_username: 
  proxy_password: 
Package Control: Trying to execute command /usr/bin/curl --user-agent 'Sublime Package Control     v2.0.0' --connect-timeout 30 -sSL --compressed --dump-header /tmp/tmpueshe5 --cacert   /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -v https://codeload.github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson/zip/master
reloading Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
found 1 files for base name Default.sublime-theme
Package Control: Curl HTTP Debug General
  Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    Trying 192.30.252.147...
  Connected to codeload.github.com (192.30.252.147) port 443 (#0)
  error setting certificate verify locations:
    CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  Closing connection 0
    CAfile: /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
Package Control: Error downloading package. curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:     downloading https://codeload.github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson/zip/master.
error: Package Control

Unable to download Pretty JSON. Please view the console for more details.
```

Comment: I'm having this error. Package Control: Error downloading channel. URL error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known downloading https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.
Package Control: Error downloading repository. URL error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known downloading https://api.github.com/repos/n1k0/SublimeHighlight.
error: Package Control

There are no packages available for installation

Comment: Make sure Little Snitch isn't blocking the request (that was my problem, after months of not knowing)

Comment: I shut down Sublime, waited 10 minutes, started it, tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 39):

Had the same issue today. Reinstalled package control:

- Deleted Package Control folder inside the Sublime Text 3 > Packages folder
- went to https://sublime.wbond.net/installation and executed the manual installation instructions there

...namely

1. Click the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu
2. Browse up a folder and then into the Installed Packages/ folder
3. Download Package Control.sublime-package and copy it into the Installed Packages/ directory
4. Restart Sublime Text

Worked like charm!

Comment: this didn't work for me. Will Bond advised getting the latest from the master branch of the GitHub Package Control repository into the sublime packages folder. It works fine now.

Here's a link to the issue raised on GitHub: https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/745

It describes the problem and the solution.

Comment: The easier way of saying this is: "Go to Preferences -> Browse Packages, delete the Package Control.sublime-package, run the code from https://sublime.wbond.net/installation, restart Sublime."

Comment: I just reinstall the Package Control with the ['simple' instructions](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) and worked for me. I am under ST3 Build 3103

Comment: 'Package Control.sublime-package' would need to be removed from the _**Installed** Packages_ folder. 
A simple reinstall with the [provided script](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) sufficed for me. Manual installation wasn't necessary.

Comment: After adding the proxy settings in the user configuration of Package Control, this solution worked fine on Debian.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem today in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit with Sublime Text Build 3126.

Following advice from this [Github issue page](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/959#issuecomment-168448993) solved it for me.

Copy-paste the below lines to

Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User.

```
"channels":
[
"https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json",
"https://web.archive.org/web/20150905194312/https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json"
],
```

Comment: It worked on Linux Mint 18.02. Thanks a bunch, mate.

Comment: Instead use an old json, try to download the latest and keep it on github and regularly update. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Keris/st3-channel/master/channel_v3.json

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue following an upgrade, but saw this in the readme and ran this python script which fixed it for me (ctrl + ' to bring up the console then ran the following command)

```
import urllib.request,os,sys; exec("if sys.version_info < (3,) or os.name != 'nt': raise OSError('This code is for Windows ST3 only!')"); pr='Preferences.sublime-settings'; ip='ignored_packages'; n='Package Control'; s=sublime.load_settings(pr); ig=s.get(ip); ig.append(n); s.set(ip,ig); sublime.save_settings('Preferences.sublime-settings'); pf=n+'.sublime-package'; urllib.request.install_opener(urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.ProxyHandler())); by=urllib.request.urlopen('https://packagecontrol.io/'+pf.replace(' ','%20')).read(); open(os.path.join(sublime.installed_packages_path(),pf),'wb').write(by); ig.remove(n); s.set(ip,ig); sublime.save_settings(pr); print('Package Control: 3.0.0 upgrade successful!')
```

Comment: Stopped just short of executing an unreferenced Python script in my live environment...I'd recommend the solution below - adding those channels to your package-control settings.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue yesterday and tried @Juri's answer but it didn't work because I couldn't download `Package Control.sublime-package` due to network error. Then, I tried to install a package today normally and it works. So, the problem is related to the server of package manager (https://packagecontrol.io/) and you should wait until the problem is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, when I manually hit https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json . I get a 404

Answer (score 4):

Check proxy setting in

```
Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – Default / User
```

If the proxy setting is invalid, you would get this error too.

Comment: And... what do you mean by "if the proxy setting is invalid" How do we know when it is valid or not?

Comment: it means the proxy server is down.

Comment: You need to add `"http_proxy": "<proxy>:<port>"` to  the file Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. I was using Sublime Text 3 on MAC OS Catalina 10.15.6

Below change resolved issue like gem!

Go to

```
Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – Default / User
```

And add below lines

```
"downloader_precedence":  
{  
    "linux": [ "curl","wget","urllib"],  
    "osx":   ["curl","wget","urllib"]  
}
```

Comment: This was the one that fixed it for me, on WSL Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I was lately experiencing incidents related with SSL verification with curl, apt-get, wget, and in an attempt to install packages with Sublime :

```
SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

Surfing on the net I find out that there's a package that manage the ca-certificates and that is :

```
mlazo@mlazo-pc:~$ dpkg -l |grep -i ca-certificates
ii  ca-certificates                                                  20201027ubuntu0.18.04.1                             all          Common CA certificates
```

So I proceed to reinstall it, with the following steps :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Once the main package is been re-installed, I proceed to install a package on Sublime with the keytrokes "**Cntrl + Shift + P**" getting a successfull outcome.

I really hope this information would be helpful for somebody else.

Best regards,

Manuel Lazo

Answer (score 0):

Try again now. I think the web admin fixed the certificate problem -- you may need to delete the package control file and install it again (but you can keep settings and other packages already installed).

Also, seems to fail if you don't have **cURL** installed, but you do.

Comment: installing package control from console gives error

    Package Control: Error downloading channel. b'curl: (77) error     setting certificate verify locations:\n  CAfile: /usr/lib    /ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt\n  CApath: /etc/ssl   /certs' downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
    Package Control: Error downloading channel. b'curl: (77) error   setting certificate verify locations:\n  CAfile: /usr/lib /ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt\n  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs'   downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/channel.json.
    Package Control: No updated packages

Comment: Additionally, I sought help on the Package Control github repo. Following Will's triage steps, my _ca-certificates.crt_ is empty for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package using the manual method (follow these steps):

- Click the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu
- Browse up a folder and then into the Installed Packages/ folder
- Download Package Control.sublime-package and copy it into the Installed Packages/ directory
- Restart Sublime Text

Then don't forget to add your proxy and port to the file `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User` like so:

`"http_proxy": "[proxy]:[port]"`

Answer (score 0):

The project maintainer is having a problem with the package control server at the time of writing this.

See https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-outage/41274/31 for more information on the restoration progress or if you wish to offer support.

Meanwhile, in order to access packages you wish to install, you can search google for the package name and use the cached google page to find the package's project page.

For example, you could search "sublime text 3 predawn" and go to the packages project page (in this case github) to download and install it manually.

[image: Search Results]

Navigate to the project page from the cached package control page. The project page will give you access to the package as well as manual install procedures.

[image: Package Control Cached]

Answer (score 0):

Working Answer is here: 
[FIX] Sublime Error - There Are Not Packages Available For Installation - 100% working

https://mrmoeed.blogspot.com/2019/09/fix-sublime-error-there-are-not.html

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, console was showing 403 error at https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.

I had to download the file manually and change the channel to the file in my computer. Not sure if that's most reliable way, as you probably would need to download the file again to see most recent packages, but it's the only thing that worked for me.

So just download the file from: https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json

Add the file to your channel in:

prefernces > package settings > package control > settings - user.

Like this:

```
"channels":
[
    "C:\\Users\\YourUser\\Downloads\\channel_v3.json"
],
```

Answer (score -2):

## For Mac Users :: Solution Here what you need to do.

Open System Preference -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies
then remove everything from the proxies Text area.
uncheck Use FTP mode.

thats's it.

Quit Sublime, restart again  and hit CMD+Shift+P